# Web service Google o similar

Tags: java, webservice, netbeans, web

tengo que hacer para clase un web service de google o alguno similar en netbenas. Tengo que utilizar java, y llevo vario tiempo mirando como hacer, pero no encuentro ningun ejemplo. Los de google, al parecer, no usan web service, son una api que metes el link, y ya esta. Alguno me puede iluminar en este tema. He probado varios proyectos, pero en ninguno me e acercado a lo que necesito.

Comment: ¿Te refieres a crear un servicio web para desplegarlo en GAE?

Comment: Tiene que ser en netbeans, no me vale el que puedes crear con google.

Comment: En Netbeans lo puedes codear, es igual que programarlo en Eclipse, IntelliJ o notepad. GAE es el entorno de ejecución propio de Google. O sino, no entiendo lo que intentas hacer.

Comment: Por ejemplo,el que he mirado, el de direcciones de google, que metes una direccion en coordenadas,y te muestra la zona del mapa que corresponden, o el de login de google. Ambos estan semi-implementados en netbeans como web services predefinidos,pero no se como completarlos :S

Comment: ¿Necesitas crear un servicio por REST o por WSDL?

Comment: Un WSDL creo,aunque no se si por REST me podria valer... pero en principio WSDL

Comment: Bueno, en Netbeans hay una opción para crear un proyecto de tipo servicio. Al final te crea una aplicación Web y te provee el esquema para que generes tus clases que luego generarán el WSDL por ti mediante JAX-WS.

Comment: Acabo de hablar con el profesor,y si me sirve REST, y me acaba de decir,que es lo que quiere... me vuelve loco:S , he estado mirando el de google directions, que metes una direccion y te enseña el mapa de la zona, pero es en JS... y necesito en java